# Can`t set the min investement value

Tags: solidity, contract-development

```
uint256 public max_contribution = 50 ether; 
    uint256 public min_contribution = 1 ether;
```

I added this to my ICO smart-contract, but still can do less than 1 ether transactions. What should i change there or may be how can i set minimal contribution in other way?

Comment: you can set these fields, but you need to use it in your code (transfer function)

Comment: function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    uint256 public max_contribution = 50 ether;
    uint256 public min_contribution = 1 ether;  like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require(msg.value >= min_contribution);
require(msg.value <= max_contribution);
```

This checks wether the value that was send fits your specified restrictions. If it doesn't the transaction gets reverted.
So, you need to put this at the top of your `transfer` function. Work with a `modifier` if you are checking this in multiple functions.